# Add rectangle fill to line chart

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Is it possible to add draw a rectangle as a background of Line chart? I'm using react-chartjs-2 and cannot find any examples with drawing a canvas as background...

Answer (score 1):

managed to do this with following code:

```
const plugins = [
  {
   beforeDraw: (chartInstance, easing) => {
   const ctx = chartInstance.chart.ctx;
   ctx.fillStyle = "lightgreen";
   ctx.fillRect(30, 200, 955, 50);
  },
 },
];
//...
<Line
    data={data}
    plugins={plugins}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can draw it before the Line chart with `drawTime: 'beforeDatasetsDraw'`